# Custom Input field inside AntDesign form - "A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled."

Tags: reactjs, input, antd

So I like to use AntDesign's forms cuz i like how their validation works. However I wanted to change the `Input` component to make it more personalized for my website. So I made my `CustomInput` component and replaced it by their `Input` component. Everything works fine. My values are caught by their `onFinish` function and everything. However idk why the console is mad at me and keeps telling me theres an input component thats not controlled.

```
A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. 
This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. 
Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

Im tempted to just ignore it as theres literally nothing wrong with how it works.

Heres the code:

```
const CustomInput = styled.input`
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 0.2px solid #d1d1d1;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 8px 18px;
    width: 290px;
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 13pt;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    &::placeholder {
        color: #ababab;
        font-weight: 200;
    }
`;

const CustomeBtn = styled.button`
    background-color: #293651;
    color: #f7f5fb;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #ffbb33;
        color: black;
    }
`;

const CustomLink = styled(Link)`
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #293651;
    text-align: center;

    &:hover {
        color: #ffbb33;
    }
`;

function Login() {
    const onFinish = (values) => {
        console.log("Received values of form: ", values);
    };

    return (
        <MainContainer>
            <Heading>Login</Heading>
            <LoginIcon />
            <Form
                name="normal_login"
                className="login-form"
                initialValues={{
                    remember: true,
                }}
                onFinish={onFinish}
            >
                <Form.Item
                    name="username"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: "Please input your Username!",
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    ---------My custom input-----------
                    <CustomInput placeholder="Username" autoComplete='on'/>
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item
                    name="password"
                    rules={[
                        {
                            required: true,
                            message: "Please input your Password!",
                        },
                    ]}
                >
                    -----------My custom input-------------
                    <CustomInput type="password" placeholder="Password" autoComplete='on' />
                </Form.Item>

                <Form.Item>
                    <CustomeBtn htmlType="submit">Login</CustomeBtn>
                    Or <CustomLink to="/register">register now!</CustomLink>
                </Form.Item>
            </Form>
        </MainContainer>
```

Whats weird is that when i add a `value` attribute to my input field, it doesnt pick it up. Like if i add `value='this'`, it wont show up and itll let me type in the field normally so....whats happening

Comment: You forgot the important part of your code which is the code for `CustomInput`. As the error says: If you provide a `value` prop to a built-in `<input />` element it should never change from `undefined` to something else.

Comment: What do you mean? I dont need to provide any more code to my custom input. Its an input field with a placeholder. What else is there? As i said, the onFinish method captures my values. and console logs them no problem, from there i can use them. So ant design somehow takes care of that. Also as i said, when i provide a value attribute to the custom input, it doesnt register it. As if its not even there.

Comment: What I asked for is if you can provide the code of your `CustomInput` component.

Comment: @trixn oh theres no code. Im using styled-components. Look at the top, i defined it there. Its just an html input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your input has no initial value provided either in `initialValues` on the `Form` or via `initialValue` on the `Form.Item`. Therefore when you first enter a value it changes from `undefined` to something else switching it from an uncontrolled input to a controlled one.

React considers this a potential mistake as inputs should be either controlled (always provided a value other than `undefined`) or never given any value (in which case the value is managed by the input element itself). They shouldn't change from one to the other while being mounted.

Either provide an initial value in `initialValues` or in `initialValue`:

```
<Form
    name="normal_login"
    className="login-form"
    initialValues={{
        remember: true,
        Username: '',
        password: '',
    }}
    onFinish={onFinish}
>
```

or

```
<Form.Item name="username" initialValue="">{/* ... */}</Form.Item>
```

You could also use the `Input` component from `antd` which also sets a sane initial value on the underlying input element depending on the type if none is provided.

Comment: Thank you thats great. I just realized i couldve just done `const CustomInput = styled(Input)` thus kinda inheriting everything from the antd Input component. Your solution works just as well tho

Comment: @SaifeldeenAdel Glad it helped.